# Search the current folder

Tags: vba, excel

This Excel VBA code creates hyperlinks to a list of items in Column A, to corresponding folder names from a FIXED location. For example:

```
 Room101 is hyperlinked to C:\Files\Pictures\Room101

 Room102 is hyperlinked to C:\Files\Pictures\Room102

 Room103 is hyperlinked to C:\Files\Pictures\Room103
```

I have been trying to redesign the folder destination to be more dynamic, specifically **the search folder should be the Excel file's current folder.** Please see the code below on line 7:

```
Option Explicit
Dim lngRow

Public Sub Aufruf()
    Dim lngTMP As Long
    lngTMP = ActiveSheet.Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, 1).Row
    For lngRow = 1 To lngTMP
        searchDir "M:\Pictures" 'fixed folder location
    Next lngRow
End Sub

Private Sub searchDir(strDir)
    Dim objSubDir As Object
    Dim strName As String
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objDir As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objDir = objFSO.getfolder(strDir)
    For Each objSubDir In objDir.subfolders
        strName = StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(objSubDir.Path), "\")(0))
        If strName = Cells(lngRow, 1).Text Then
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(lngRow, 1), Address:= _
                objSubDir.Path & "\", TextToDisplay:=Cells(lngRow, 1).Text
                Exit Sub
        End If
        searchDir objSubDir
    Next
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objDir = Nothing
End Sub
```

You will notice that the file path is fixed to "M:\Pictures".

How do I search the folder the Excel document is saved in? I have attempted to use variations of:

```
path = ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

Comment: VB.Net IsNot vba AndAlso VBNet.HasMacros() = False

Comment: Try `searchDir thisWorkbook.Path`. but Why this loop `For lngRow = 1 To lngTMP`??

Comment: Thanks that appears to work, I will continue to test it.